# R ggplot: time series bbar chart has leading and lagging spaces

Tags: r, ggplot2

Recently, you guys helped me format the x-axis of my chart as a date axis:

[R ggplot2: bar chart of a time series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912294/r-ggplot2-bar-chart-of-a-time-series/37912579#37912579)

My data spans from July 2006 to June 2016 but R is automatically making the scale of the x-axis include all of 2006 and all of 2016.  This results in 'blank space' on either end of the chart.  I would also like for the labels to have Jul 20XX instead of every December.  I tried forcing it to fit my data with the command:

```
scale_x_date(limits = c(min, max), breaks=date_breaks("12 months"), labels=date_format("%b %Y")) +
```

but it that doesn't seem to change anything except it reformatted my labels as Dec 20XX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `g` as the plot object from the answer posted to the liked question:

```
dates_vec <- as.Date(rownames(sample), "%m/%d/%Y")
dates_for_breaks <- c(seq.Date(from = min(dates_vec), 
                                   to = max(dates_vec), by = "year"), max(dates_vec))

g + scale_x_date(breaks = dates_for_breaks, date_labels = "%b %Y", expand = c(0, 0))
```

gives

[image]

If you want the labels every 2 years:

```
dates_for_breaks <- c(seq.Date(from = min(dates_vec), 
                                   to = max(dates_vec), by = "2 years"), max(dates_vec))
```

Comment: thank you!  adding the expand parameter to scale_x_date was the key.